# Compilation issue with Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I've just been introduced to pointers in C, and have been playing around with them to try and get more familiar with them.

Can someone explain to my why the code below doesn't compile?

```
int *high = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)),*low = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*high = 100;
*low = 0;
```

Comment: whats your compilation error

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/); this works perfectly fine for me: http://ideone.com/jsdSzr

Comment: Are we to assume that this code is wrapped in a correctly defined `main` function or have you tried to compile that code as it is displayed here?

Comment: 1. When compiling in C, don't cast malloc(). 2. Ensure `<stdlib.h>` is included. 3. Please tell us the error as well as a short copy of your code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Well, the code is not inside a function, so you can't really do function calls to initialize the global variables, or use non-declaration statements like that. Put inside a function, it compiles fine. [Counter-opinion: DO cast malloc() and DO set the appropriate compiler flags that will complain about missing prototypes for ANY function, not just malloc()].

Comment: is this all that you have written or its just a snippet... If snippet then kindly share the basic complete code

Answer (score 1):

If you have #included stdlib.h it should compile.

To ensure that your code is correct, replace it with this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *high = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *low  = malloc(sizeof(int));

if(high == NULL || low == NULL)
{
  // no memory, error handling here
}

*high = 100;
*low = 0;

...

free(high);
free(low);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the code like shown below whould make it compile and work as expected:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *high = malloc(sizeof(int)),*low = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *high = 100;
  *low = 0;

  return 0;
}
```

Anyway, the code lacks error checking on system calls. Always check the return value of system calls, In the case of `malloc()` a value of `NULL` would be returned if memory could not have been allocated as requested. In such case the line

```
*high = 100;
```

would most likely cause the program to crash, as dereferencing `*NULL` provokes undefined behavior.

---

In C it is **not** necessary to cast functions returning a value of `void*`. Even more it is not recommended to do so, as doing so might hide errors, for example if protoyping for the function in question is missing, the error/warning which would be given by the compiler without casting is surpressed if using casting.